# Android BottomNavigationView weird behavior

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

The complete reference of the BottomNavigationView used is:

```
com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
```

The scenario is as follows, imagine you have 1 activity with a navigation menu at the bottom, the menu has 5 items (A, B, C, D, E), and there are also 2 hidden fragments (F, G) , all fragments extend `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`

`bottom_nav_menu.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu android:id="@+id/menu_menu" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/navigation_a" android:title="" />
    <item android:id="@+id/navigation_b" android:title="" />
    <item android:id="@+id/navigation_c" android:title="" />
    <item android:id="@+id/navigation_d" android:title="" />
    <item android:id="@+id/navigation_e" android:title="" />

</menu>
```

`navigation_default.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<navigation android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation" app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_a">

    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_a" tools:layout="@layout/fragment_a" />
    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_b" tools:layout="@layout/fragment_b" />
    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_c" tools:layout="@layout/fragment_c" />
    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_d" tools:layout="@layout/fragment_d" />
    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_e" tools:layout="@layout/fragment_e" />
    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_f" tools:layout="@layout/fragment_f" /><!-- hidden -->
    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_g" tools:layout="@layout/fragment_g" /><!-- hidden -->

</navigation>
```

Activity.java:

```
AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
    R.id.navigation_a,
    R.id.navigation_b,
    R.id.navigation_c,
    R.id.navigation_d,
    R.id.navigation_e,
    R.id.navigation_f,
    R.id.navigation_g).build();

NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main);

NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);

NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(activityMainBinding.navView, navController);
```

I use `navController.navigate(destination)` to navigate to these hidden fragments, in general the method will handle any automatic transitions made by the program, to reproduce the problem let's say you are in a visible fragment, for example **C**, now if we use the `navigate` function to go from C to **F** `navController.navigate(R.id.navigation_f)`, then again from F to **A** `navController.navigate(R.id.navigation_a)`, if the user manually clicks on **C** it will redirect him to A (which means the content of A will be displayed rather than the content of C), and what I noticed that to avoid this weird behavior I need to close the automatic circle, which means the cycle should be: [C->F->C->A] rather than: [C->F->A], any better options?

Comment: Each tab has its own back stack (that's the key part to [multiple back stacks](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/multiple-back-stacks-b714d974f134)), so if you make C's stack of C->F->A, then yeah, you'll go to A when you reselect the tab associated with C. Are you trying to swap stacks entirely when you navigate to A (i.e., have a stack of C->F associated with C, and a separate stack of A associated with A)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up using `actions` instead of navigating directly to a specific fragment, an action must have a `source` and a `destination`, so rather than using `R.id.navigation_f` I used `R.id.action_c_to_f`, to keep things simple, I created a class to handle all `possible` transitions in the app:

`Navigation.java:`

```
public class Navigation {
    /**/
    public static void navigate(@IdRes int resId){
        /**/
        int[] destinations = new int[]{
            /**/
            R.id.navigation_a,
            R.id.navigation_b,
            R.id.navigation_c,
            R.id.navigation_d,
            R.id.navigation_e,
            R.id.navigation_f,
            R.id.navigation_g
        };
        /**/
        int[] actions = new int[]{
            /**/
            R.id.action_c_to_f,
            R.id.action_f_to_a,
            /**/
        };
        /**/
        int[][] transitions = new int[][]{
            /**/
            new int[]{ 2, 5, actions[0] }, // R.id.navigation_c -> R.id.navigation_f
            new int[]{ 5, 0, actions[1] }, // R.id.navigation_f -> R.id.navigation_a
            /**/
        };
        /**/
        int i = indexOf(destinations, navController.getCurrentDestination().getId());
        /**/
        int j = indexOf(destinations, resId);
        /**/
        for (int k = 0; k < transitions.length; k++){
            /**/
            if (transitions[k][0] == i && transitions[k][1] == j){
                /**/
                int x = k;
                /**/
                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(() -> navController.navigate(transitions[x][2]));
                /**/
                return;
                /**/
            }
        }
    }
    /**/
    public static int indexOf(int[] array, int value){
        /**/
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            /**/
            if (array[i] == value){
                /**/
                return i;
                /**/
            }
        }
        /**/
        return -1;
        /**/
    }
}
```

`navigation_default.xml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<navigation android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation" app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_a">

    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_a" tools:layout="@layout/fragment_a" />
    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_b" tools:layout="@layout/fragment_b" />
    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_d" tools:layout="@layout/fragment_d" />
    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_e" tools:layout="@layout/fragment_e" />
    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_g" tools:layout="@layout/fragment_g" />

    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_c" tools:layout="@layout/fragment_c">

        <action android:id="@+id/action_c_to_f"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_f"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_enter_anim"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_exit_anim"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_exit_anim"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/navigation_c"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />

    </fragment>

    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_f" tools:layout="@layout/fragment_f">

        <action android:id="@+id/action_f_to_a"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_a"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_enter_anim"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_exit_anim"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_exit_anim"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/navigation_a"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />

    </fragment>

</navigation>
```

Note: I believe this issue is related to an internal bug in Android, this is just a workaround until this issue is resolved, normally navigating directly to a specific fragment should work without interfering with manual navigation of the user, this should work as if the user manually jumped to the `visible|hidden` fragment.